# Wordpress limit posts per page with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, posts

I want to create blog page with recent posts and pagination. Code below shows recent posts but pagination doesn't want to work.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container clearfix">
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
<?php
   $postslist = get_posts('numberposts=-1&posts_per_page=5&order=DESC&orderby=date');
         foreach ($postslist as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div class="entry">
    <div class="recent-post-thumbnail">
        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail($recent->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">More ></a></h4>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div> <!-- end content -->
<div class="kreska-pion"></div>
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`numberposts=6` replace this with `post_per_page` and let me know if It worked .

```
<?php
    $postlist = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&posts_per_page=5' );
    $posts = array();
    foreach ( $postlist as $post ) {
       $posts[] += $post->ID;
    }

    $current = array_search( get_the_ID(), $posts );
    $prevID = $posts[$current-1];
    $nextID = $posts[$current+1];
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
    <div class="navigation">
    <?php if ( !empty( $prevID ) ): ?>
    <div class="alignleft">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prevID ); ?>"
      title="<?php echo get_the_title( $prevID ); ?>">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <?php endif;
    if ( !empty( $nextID ) ): ?>
    <div class="alignright">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $nextID ); ?>" 
     title="<?php echo get_the_title( $nextID ); ?>">Next</a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .navigation -->
```

Comment: Now this line looks like that: 
$postslist = get_posts('post_per_page=6&order=DESC&orderby=date');
But shows just 5 posts and there is still only one page of posts.
Am i missing something in function.php? Or what's wrong with it?
Thank you, Prafulla, for you help, I believe it will start to work soon :)

Comment: var_dump( $postlist ); with `get_posts('post_per_page' = -1)` and post the output.

Comment: Can you try the updated code in place of your loop ?